# Retrieving the most recent communication from a user

Tags: sql, mysql

Could someone review an [accepted answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644093/returning-first-result-where-case-result-x/5680184#5680184) I gave on Stack Overflow?

The use-case is as follows:

> Given a messaging system where a user
>   can receive a message from a single
>   user and send messages to one or more
>   users, return the most recent
>   communication (sent or received)
>   between a passed userId and the
>   individual(s) that user communicated
>   with.

For the example, I have three tables:

**Users**

> ```
> id   user_name
> 1    Walker
> 2    John
> 3    Kate
> ```

**Messages**

> ```
> id   senderid   body                                 time
> 1    1          ignored 1                            2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
> 2    1          ignored 2                            2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
> 3    3          ignored 3                            2010-04-03 00:00:00.000
> 4    1          msg A to john and kate               2010-04-10 00:00:00.000
> 5    3          msg b from kate to walker and john   2010-04-11 00:00:00.000
> ```

**`messages_recipients`**

> ```
> id   messageid   userid
> 1    1           2
> 2    1           3
> 3    2           2
> 4    3           1
> 5    4           2
> 6    4           3
> 7    5           1
> 8    5           2
> ```

The data is tailored in such a way that I want a list of communications between user Walker and the people Walker has spoken with.

You can see a list of these messages by running the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    u2.user_name AS Sender, 
    u1.user_name AS Receiver, 
    m.body, 
    m.time
FROM 
    messages m
JOIN 
    messages_recipients mr ON m.id = mr.messageid
JOIN 
    users u1 ON mr.userid = u1.id
JOIN 
    users u2 ON m.senderid = u2.id
ORDER BY 
    time DESC
```

Now that we have the test scenario, the part I want reviewed: returning the most recently communicated message between Walker, John, and Kate.

```sql
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId INT = 1

    --A.  Main Query
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN mtemp.senderid = 1 --@UserId 
                THEN 
                    CONCAT('Message To:  ', receivers.user_name)
                ELSE 
                    CONCAT('Message From:  ' , senders.user_name)
                END AS MessageType, 
        mtemp.body, 
        mtemp.time 
    FROM 
        messages mtemp 
        INNER JOIN users senders ON 
            mtemp.senderid = senders.id 
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            --B.  Inner Query determining most recent message (based on time) 
            --    between @UserID and the person @UserID 
            --    Communicated with (either as sender or receiver)
            select userid,max(maxtime) as maxmaxtime from
                (
                    --C.1.  First part of Union Query Aggregating sent/received messages on passed @UserId
                    SELECT 
                        m2.body,
                        kk.* 
                    FROM 
                        `messages` m2 INNER JOIN
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    userid,
                                    MAX(m.time) AS MaxTime
                                FROM
                                    messages m INNER JOIN
                                        messages_recipients mr  ON m.id = mr.messageid AND
                                        m.senderid = 1 --@UserId
                                GROUP BY
                                    mr.userid
                            ) kk on m2.time = kk.MaxTime and m2.senderid = 1 --@UserId

                    UNION
                    --C.2.  Second part of Union Query Aggregating sent/received messages on passed @UserId
                    SELECT 
                        m1.body,
                        jj.* 
                    FROM 
                        `messages` m1 INNER JOIN
                        ----C.2a.  Inner most query of users users who sent message to userid
                        (SELECT DISTINCT
                                senderid as userid,
                                MAX(m.time) AS MaxTime
                            FROM
                                messages m INNER JOIN
                                    messages_recipients mr  ON m.id = mr.messageid AND
                                    mr.userid = 1 --@UserId
                            GROUP BY
                                m.senderid) jj on m1.time = jj.MaxTime and m1.senderid = jj.userid 
                 )       MaximumUserTime
             group by 
                MaximumUserTime.userid 
             ) AggregatedData on mtemp.time = AggregatedData.maxmaxtime 
                    INNER JOIN users receivers on AggregatedData.userid = receivers.id 
            ORDER BY `time` DESC
END
```

To test in `phpMyAdmin`, you'll have to remove the comments and the `BEGIN`/`END` `DECLARE` statements as well.  I just wanted to post this as if it would look in a procedure.

When I run this query I get the following results:

> ```
> MessageType              body                                  time
> Message From:  Kate    msg b from kate to walker and john    2010-04-11 00:00:00.000
> Message To:  John      msg A to john and kate                2010-04-10 00:00:00.000
> ```

That's the most recent communications concerning Walker among all those users who have communicated with Walker.

Is there a better way to run this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution has a similar complexity to yours (14 steps in `EXPLAIN`), assuming MySQL's query optimizer is smart enough.  However, in my opinion, this formulation will be much easier to understand.

```
SELECT  IF(recipientid,
           CONCAT('Message To: ', recipient.user_name),
           CONCAT('Message From: ', sender.user_name)) AS MessageType,
        body,
        time
    FROM
        ( -- Join messages with recipients, relabeling userids in terms of interlocutor and self
            SELECT messageid, time, body, NULL AS senderid, userid AS recipientid, userid AS interlocutor, senderid AS self
                FROM messages_recipients
                    INNER JOIN messages
                        ON messages.id = messageid
            UNION
            SELECT messages.id, time, body, senderid, NULL, senderid, userid
                FROM messages_recipients
                    INNER JOIN messages
                        ON messages.id = messageid
        ) AS thread_latest
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS recipient
            ON recipient.id = recipientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS sender
            ON sender.id = senderid
    WHERE
        -- Discard all but the latest message in each thread
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT messageid
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT messageid, time, userid AS interlocutor, senderid AS self
                        FROM messages_recipients
                            INNER JOIN messages
                                ON messages.id = messageid
                    UNION
                    SELECT messages.id, time, senderid, userid
                        FROM messages_recipients
                            INNER JOIN messages
                                ON messages.id = messageid
                ) AS thread_later
                WHERE
                    thread_later.self = thread_latest.self AND
                    thread_later.interlocutor = thread_latest.interlocutor AND
                    thread_later.time > thread_latest.time
            ) AND
        self = 1 --@UserId
    ORDER BY time DESC;
```

The main insight is that once you relabel senders and recipients in terms of interlocutor and self, it's just a simple matter of filtering out the results.  Retain only those messages where `self` is the user in question.  Then, every row that has the same `interlocutor` conceptually constitutes a thread.

Notice that there is a subquery that appears twice.  We can make it clearer by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW threads AS
    -- Messages I sent
    SELECT messageid, time, body, NULL AS senderid, userid AS recipientid, userid AS interlocutor, senderid AS self
        FROM messages_recipients
            INNER JOIN messages
                ON messages.id = messageid
    UNION
    -- Messages I received
    SELECT messages.id, time, body, senderid, NULL, senderid, userid
        FROM messages_recipients
            INNER JOIN messages
                ON messages.id = messageid;

SELECT  IF(recipientid,
           CONCAT('Message To: ', recipient.user_name),
           CONCAT('Message From: ', sender.user_name)) AS MessageType,
        body,
        time
    FROM
        threads AS thread_latest
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS recipient
            ON recipient.id = recipientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS sender
            ON sender.id = senderid
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT messageid
                FROM threads AS thread_later
                WHERE
                    thread_later.self = thread_latest.self AND
                    thread_later.interlocutor = thread_latest.interlocutor AND
                    thread_later.time > thread_latest.time
            ) AND
        self = 1 --@UserId
    ORDER BY time DESC;
```

---

I'll take this opportunity to point out that this query is where PostgreSQL really shines.  Two features in PostgreSQL (since version 8.4) make it easy.  The [`WITH` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/queries-with.html) lets you define a helper view in the query itself.  More importantly, 
[window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tutorial-window.html) let you partition the threads by interlocutor, which is precisely the tricky part about this problem.

```
WITH threads(messageid, time, body, senderid, recipientid, interlocutor, self) AS (
    -- Messages I sent
    SELECT messageid, time, body, NULL, userid, userid, senderid
        FROM messages_recipients
            INNER JOIN messages
                ON messages.id = messageid
    UNION
    -- Messages I received
    SELECT messages.id, time, body, senderid, NULL, senderid, userid
        FROM messages_recipients
            INNER JOIN messages
                ON messages.id = messageid
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN recipientid IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'Message To: ' || recipient.user_name
           ELSE 'Message From: ' || sender.user_name
        END AS MessageType,
        body,
        time
   FROM (
        SELECT  *,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY interlocutor ORDER BY time DESC) AS thread_pos
            FROM threads
            WHERE self = 1 --@UserId
        ) AS my_threads
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS recipient
            ON recipient.id = recipientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS sender
            ON sender.id = senderid
    WHERE thread_pos = 1 -- Only the latest message per thread
    ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give a detailed answer to this 2+ year old question.